# Formatting numbers coming from dataset to include commas for thousands in Carto map legend?

Tags: carto, legend

I'm using carto.js v4 to build my map. The legend I've put together displays some of the data as numbers next to value scaled markers
As example I have:

```
    document.getElementById('gasDistmax').innerHTML = `
      <div class="gasDistCircle circle-outline" style="width:20px; height:20px;"></div> <p>${metadata.getMax()}<br />(MCF)</p>
```

The ${metadata.getMax()} gives me 585457. I would like to present that number as 585,457. It would be preferable to not change the actual column format in the db or add an extra column formatted as a string.

Is there a javascript way to do this, either within the carto library or one of the js.min libraries?

I've been building this from various online examples but have yet to find anything to reformat the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If adding additional libraries is an issue, you can use `Intl`, the [Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl), almost all modern browsers [support it](https://caniuse.com/#search=Intl).

```
var number = 123456.789;
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-EN',{ useGrouping: true, maximumFractionDigits:0})
formatter.format(number)
//output: "123,456"
```

Comment: Jorge Sanz's suggestion worked great! I would imagine that Ivan's would have as well but it's nice to not need a library and browser support is pretty comprehensive, at least for my user base.

Comment: Great, btw Ivan and I are coworkers at CARTO ^__^

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library to do that.

For instance, the example on `numeral.js` function `format` is exactly what you're looking for.

```
var string = numeral(1000).format('0,0');
// '1,000'
```